# open3d live mesh rendering?

Tags: rendering, mesh, open3d

I am looking for a way to nicely render **live meshes** with open3d.

A logical way to do this would be to use the add_geometry() method. However, I am facing two issues  described below:

1. I need to render the wireframe of the mesh (I have no colour - and without colour my mesh is invisible).
2. some triangles obtained with the BPA algorithm seem to be reversed and are not visible from the front view.

While the draw_geometries() method allowing to implements 1 and 2 above, it is a blocking rendering, on the other hand, the non-blocking add_geometry() does not accept the necessary options.

So, I am looking for a way to either 1) render draw_geometries() non-blocking, or 2) passing somehow the options **mesh_show_wireframe=True** and **mesh_show_back_face=True** to the add_geometry() method.

Thank you in advance for any hint.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.